# @Autowired is showing red color

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations, autowired

[@autowired annotation is showing red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRJJR.png)

When I am using @Autowired annotation in my project, intellij is showing a red collor and doesn't working .

Comment: What do you see in the hint on hover?

Comment: Try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If it does not help, a sample project is needed. There is a possibility that some libraries are missing